# Passenger on Big Sur potential privilege escalation vulnerability detected

Tags: homebrew, passenger, macos-big-sur

New installation of `Passenger` using `homebrew` on Big Sur.  Because of the new location (I'm coming from an `El Capitan` box) of `homebrew` installations inside `/opt/homebrew`, `Passenger` isn't happy because it's something I can see from the set permissions.  The error:

```
2021/03/19 09:22:16 [warn] 85#0: 1024 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 256
[ N 2021-03-19 09:22:16.2962 31353/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1373 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2021-03-19 09:22:16.3519 31355/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1340 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2021-03-19 09:22:16.3521 31355/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ W 2021-03-19 09:22:16.3944 31355/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1007 ]: WARNING: potential privilege escalation vulnerability detected. Phusion Passenger is running as root, and part(s) of the Passenger root path (/opt/homebrew/opt/passenger/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini) can be changed by non-root user(s):

 - /opt/homebrew/opt/passenger/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini is not secure: it can be modified by user rich
 - /opt/homebrew/opt/passenger/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger is not secure: it can be modified by user rich
 - /opt/homebrew/opt/passenger/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib is not secure: it can be modified by user rich
 - /opt/homebrew/opt/passenger/libexec/src is not secure: it can be modified by user rich
 - /opt/homebrew/opt/passenger/libexec is not secure: it can be modified by user rich
 - /opt/homebrew/opt/passenger is not secure: it can be modified by user rich
 - /opt/homebrew/opt is not secure: it can be modified by user rich
 - /opt/homebrew is not secure: it can be modified by user rich
```

It is a warming, but I'm not sure if it's limping or fully functional.

Should I worry?  Should I change anything?  Will this go away?  Seems it's been designed this way, but I see warnings.

Any insight appreciated.  Thank you.